# In trying to fix my laptop power adapter, current is going through the wire but the laptop will not charge?

Tags: voltage, adapter, laptop

My laptop power adapter has recently stopped working (will no longer charge my laptop), and I would prefer to fix it if possible, instead of putting a couple hundred bucks into a new one. I used a power meter to determine if there was any current going through the wires when it was plugged into the wall, and in fact the current does go from the power bar I have it plugged into all the way to the plug that goes into the laptop itself. While this is true, I am still getting no charge. I was curious if there is anything you suggest to check to see if an easy fix is an option for this cable as it could save me a lot of money.

I own an Asus Republic of Gamers G760JW laptop with the broken power adapter: Output 19.5V 9.23A, if this makes a difference.

Any advice you could give me would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: How much power did the power meter indicate was being used by the adapter?  How do you know that there was current from the adapter to the laptop?  The power meter is an AC device and can't directly measure the output of the adapter.  You should check the voltage out of the adapter with a multimeter.  Also, it is possible that the battery in your laptop has reached the end of its useful life.

Comment: I was going to say "A couple hundred bucks? For a laptop adapter?", but then I saw the 9.23A, which is a decent amount of current.

Comment: Your comments do not, in my opinion, show if it is the adapter or the laptop itself that is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Step one is to unplug the laptop and measure the power consumed on the wire.  There will be some, due to the way power supplies work.  Then connect the laptop and see if the power increases.  The ratings on your supply suggest a max of 180 W (multiply volts by amps).  It's reasonable to expect to see at least 100 W being consumed.

Answer (score 0):

A likely cause of the issue is a broken wire between the power supply and the connector to the laptop. A quick check is to use a voltmeter with a shunt resistor (e.g. 1 kilohm) to simulate a small load and place the probes on the inside and outside of the connector. Wiggle the wire and see if the voltage changes from zero to normal. If you're lucky, the break would be in wire itself; simply cut out the bad section and splice the wire ***maintaining the same polarity***.
Another possibility is a bad connector on power supply -- you might find a replacement.
Yet another possibility is a blown fuse in the supply. Most are sealed and do not have easily replaced fuses.
In any event, Amazon and other sellers have specific and universal laptop power supplies for $10-$20, so don't worry if the unit cannot be fixed. My PC and an external HD work well from such after-market units.
The worst (likely) situation is that the connector *in the laptop* is broken. If that's the case, and if you're comfortable with opening the laptop, which may be difficult, you could replace the connector (tricky, because of multilayer PCB) or solder on an external wire and connector (a bit easier).

Comment: You're not going to find a 9A supply for $20. At least, not one that can *deliver* 9A.

Comment: True: I didn't note the specs above. However, here's one for ~$50 US and one for  ~$80: http://www.amazon.com/G46VW-BHI5N43-G46VW-BSI5N06-G75VX-BHI7N11-G750JH-DB71-G750JW-BBI7N05/dp/B00GDGXSVI/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1420094984&sr=8-1& and for $30: http://www.amazon.com/Adapter-Charger-Comapq-Presario-nx9600/dp/B00B6XX9GC/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1420094984&sr=8-7&keywords=19+volt+180+watt+power+supplykeywords=19+volt+180+watt+power+supply http://www.amazon.com/Delta-Electronics-ADP-180NB-MD98054-MD97623/dp/B009XTGZJE/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1420094984&sr=8-2&keywords=19+volt+180+watt+power+supply